# Are the following sets countable or uncountable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

I have been trying to figure out this problem for a while now,

> Determine whether the following sets are countable or uncountable. Prove your answer.
>
> a)the set of real numbers with decimal representation consisting of all 2’s (2.22 and 22.222 . . . are such numbers).
>
> b)the set of real numbers with decimal representation consisting of 2’s and 5’s

For a, i would say that it is countable due to that I can have a base of 2 to where I can count up for example 2.2, 2.22,... 222.22222 and so on.

For b, I was confused on how to even start this one.

I am just looking for a push in the right direction and if I am some what correct for the first one.

Comment: Nitpick:  The set of real numbers with decimal representations consisting only of 2's and no zeros is the empty set.  The set of real numbers consisting of only twos and trailing and leading zeros is countable.

Comment: b) if $\{0,1\}^{\infty}$ is uncountable.  If $f:\{0,1\}\rightarrow \{2,5\}: f(0) = 2; f(1) = 5$ then $\{0,1\}^{\infty}\rightarrow B$ via: $f(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f(a_i)*10^{-i}$ is an injective function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a) you're right that it's countable. However, it's not immediately obvious how to list the elements, since there are infinitely many numbers in the set which lie between $2.2$ and $22.2$. You can think of the numbers as being described by two integers (how far to the left of the decimal point it extends, and how far to the right it extends). Do you know how to show that $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is countable?

For b) you should try to construct a bijection with the real numbers, which will show it's uncountable (hint: binary).

Comment: I don't think constructing a bijection with the real numbers is the way to solve (b). After all, $2.555_\ldots\neq 5.222\ldots$, but $0.111\ldots_2=1.000\ldots_2$. Better would be to construct a bijection with $\{2,5\}^\mathbb N$ (or just doing things directly with a diagonalization argument).

Comment: @A.Howells you are correct.  It's worth noting that the cases where 0.1111..=1 and 0.0001111... = 0.001 are only countably many exceptions so you get a bijection to an uncountable set minus a countable set which can be shown to be countable.  But... just do an $\{0,1\}^N \rightarrow \{0,5\}^N \cong B$ avoids the issue entirely.

Comment: @fleablood While, as you point out, it is possible to solve the problem using Especially Lime's hint, my point was that it is easier to construct a bijection with $\{2,5\}^\mathbb N$ (or $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$) than with $\mathbb R$. Thus messing around with "uncountable sets minus a countable sets" is unnecessary, especially since $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ is easily demonstrated from first principles to be uncountable (or at the very least, showing the same for $\mathbb R$ is harder).

Comment: Right.  I absolutely agree.  It's a good trick figure the uncountability of the reals but if one thinks about it it is really a very unnescessary complication.  $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, you get used to the concept it is much more fundamental and direct and *way* easier than anything that can be said about the reals.  And the reals *do* have one very necessary evil that throws a spanner in the works  An infinite number of trailing 1s (or 9s) must be equal a terminating decimal.  So such maps are never completely injective.

Answer (score 0):

$a)$ countable Because the only freedom we have is the number of digits before the comma and the number of digits (possibly infinite) after the comma.

$b)$ Even the reals in the interval $[0,1]$ with $2$'s and $5$'s build an uncountable set which you can proof with Cantor's diagonal argument. (We have an infinite sequence with two possible values).

Comment: surely you have freedom of the number of digits after the comma too...

Comment: OP shows  examples with variation of the number of 2's both before and after the decimal

Answer (score 0):

**hint for the second:**, the question could have been $1$ and $0$ instead, which is to say every number with binary representation.

For the first one, there is a bijection between those after the decimal and $\mathbb N$, and those before with $\mathbb N$ as well. From this, it's not hard to find something that works for $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Peter, Cantor's diagonal argument is the way to do it for (b). For (a), however, you may simply note that any such number is rational.